# How to run a report in external Tomcat with JFreeChart?

Tags: java, tomcat

I just created the report with JFreeChart, and it works in Tomcat, which is embeded in MyEclipse. However, when I try to create the report in an external Tomcat and show it on browser, such as Firefox, it fails. Tomcats logs display the following error:

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader findResourceInternal
Message: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.
Could not load ehcache-version.properties. 
The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
```

Here is my code for my report:

The JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/locale/easyui-lang-zh_CN.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./js/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./js/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./js/demo.css">

  </head>

  <body>
Select start time
    <input id="startTime" class="easyui-datetimebox" required style="width:200px">
Select end time

    <input id="endTime" class="easyui-datetimebox" required style="width:200px">
    <button id="show" onclick="showChart()">Go</button>
    <label id="info"></label><br/><br/>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="p" style="width:400px;"></div> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showChart(){

            //Get the start time
            var startTime = $('#startTime').datetimebox('getValue');
            var endTime = $('#endTime').datetimebox('getValue');    
            if(startTime==null || startTime=="" || endTime==null || endTime==""){
                alert('Invalid date');
            }else{
                $('#info').empty();
                $('#info').append("<b>Please wait</b>");
                //Refresh the chart
                $('#chart').empty();
                $('#chart').append("<img src=\"jFreeCharTest?startTime="+startTime+"&endTime="+endTime+"\"></img>");
            }            

        }

        function ajaxLoading(){ 
            $("<div class=\"datagrid-mask\"></div>").css({display:"block",width:"100%",height:$(window).height()}).appendTo("body"); 
            $("<div class=\"datagrid-mask-msg\"></div>").html("Please wait").appendTo("body").css({display:"block",left:($(document.body).outerWidth(true) - 190) / 2,top:($(window).height() - 45) / 2}); 
        } 
        function ajaxLoadEnd(){ 
             $(".datagrid-mask").remove(); 
             $(".datagrid-mask-msg").remove();             
        } 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The data source:

```
 import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;

    public class DB {
        private static final String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        private static final String url="jdbc:mysql://**/**?user=**&password=**";
        public static Connection getConn(){
            Connection conn = null;
            try {
                Class.forName(driverName);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return conn;
        }

}
```

The data set and query:

```
public class JFreeCharTest extends HttpServlet {

    public JFreeCharTest() {
        super();
    }

    public void init() throws ServletException {

    }

    public void destroy() {
        super.destroy(); 
    }

    @Override  
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException,  
            IOException {  
        doGet(request, response);  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  

        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");  
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();  
        //Get the parameter
        String startTime = request.getParameter("startTime");
        String endTime = request.getParameter("endTime");
        //get the result
        CategoryDataset ds = getDataSet(startTime,endTime);  
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D(  
                "The total number of TTC buses", //Graph title 
                "The TTC routes", //X-Label 
                "The number of TTC buses", //Y-Label  
                ds, //dataset 
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, //Orientation of graph  
                true, //Generating example
                false, //Generating tool 
                false);         //Generating url 

        CategoryPlot categoryplot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();  

        NumberAxis numberaxis = (NumberAxis) categoryplot.getRangeAxis();  

        CategoryAxis domainAxis = categoryplot.getDomainAxis();  

        /*title in x coordinate*/  
        domainAxis.setTickLabelFont(new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 11));  

        /*the font style in x coordinate*/  
        domainAxis.setLabelFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12));  

        /*title in y coordinate*/  
        numberaxis.setTickLabelFont(new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));  

        /*font style in y coordinate*/  
        numberaxis.setLabelFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12));  


        chart.getLegend().setItemFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12));  


        chart.getTitle().setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12));  

        try {  
            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(out, 0.5f, chart, 1240, 400, null);  
        } finally {  
            try {  
                out.close();  
            } catch (Exception ex) {  
                ex.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
    }  



    private CategoryDataset getDataSet(String startTime,String endTime) { 
        DefaultCategoryDataset ds = new DefaultCategoryDataset(); 
        try{
            //Connecting database
            Connection cn = DB.getConn();
            System.out.println("Searching");
            String sql = "select count(distinct ttc.vehicle_id) as vc,ttc.routeTag,ttc_routes.title,ttc.dateTime from ttc INNER JOIN ttc_routes ON ttc.routeTag = ttc_routes.routeTag WHERE ttc.dateTime >= '"+startTime+"' and ttc.dateTime <= '"+endTime+"' GROUP BY ttc_routes.title order by vc desc limit 10";
            PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("Searching end");
            while(rs.next()){
                ds.addValue(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(3));
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return ds;  
    }  


}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Look through the logs and see what actually stopped the web server? There must be some indication above the lines you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are issues with the CLASSPATH of the external tomcat. Make sure any libraries that were in your eclipse project are included within the server's class path or ${tomcat}/server/lib  directory.

Also any .properties, .xml, or other config is located in the classpath as well.